# How to get the searched text in a string?

Tags: android, search, text, substring, indexof

I want to get a text that it is a part of an string.For example: I have a string like "I am Vahid" and I want to get everything that it's after "am".
The result will be "Vahid"
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

**Example1**

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("am");
separated[0]; // I am
separated[1]; // Vahid
```

**Example2**

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, "am");
String first = tokens.nextToken();// I am
String second = tokens.nextToken(); //Vahid
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed it.GoodLuck

Comment: I'm glad to listen that. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String text = "I am Vahid";
String after = "am";
int index = text.indexOf(after);
String result = "";
if(index != -1){
    result = text.substring(index + after.length());
}
System.out.print(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use like this, call the method with your string.

```
public String trimString(String stringyouwanttoTrim)
{
  if(stringyouwanttoTrim.contains("I am")
  {
    return stringyouwanttoTrim.split("I am")[1].trim();
  }
  else
  {
    return stringyouwanttoTrim;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to split your sentence by blank space you could do like this :

```
 String [] myStringElements = "I am Vahid".split(" ");
 System.out.println("your name is " + myStringElements[myStringElements.length - 1]);
```